# TableViewCell.xib doesn't appear on tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview

Here is my code, it is supposed to display the users inside firebase database in customs tableviewcell.xib but when launching the app the tableview stays empty, I really don't know what's wrong in the code or what's missing, I think it is a really simple mistake but I can't figure it out.
Thanks in advance for those who will answer.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
class UsersTableView: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

// Outlets.
@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

// Var.
var user = [User]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    retrieveUsers()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func retrieveUsers() {
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("users").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { DataSnapshot in

        let users = DataSnapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
        self.user.removeAll()
        for (_, value) in users{
            //let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
            if let uid = value["userID"] as? String{
                if uid != Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid {
                    let userToShow = User()
                    if let fullName = value["username"] as? String , let imagePath = value["photoURL"] as? String {
                        userToShow.username = fullName
                        userToShow.imagePath = imagePath
                        userToShow.userID = uid
                        self.user.append(userToShow)

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        self.tableview.reloadData()
    })
    ref.removeAllObservers()
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return  1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UserCell", for: indexPath) as! UserTableViewCell

    cell.nameLabel.text = self.user[indexPath.row].username
    cell.userID = self.user[indexPath.row].userID
    cell.userImage.downloadImage(from: self.user[indexPath.row].imagePath!)
    //checkFollowing(indexPath: indexPath)

    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return user.count ?? 0
}
  }

  extension UIImageView{

func downloadImage(from imgURL: String!) {
    let url = URLRequest(url: URL(string: imgURL)!)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil{
            print(error)
            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
  }
```

Comment: I see two steps here. Are you getting the data to the `user`? If yes, then you can check your tableViewCell data

Comment: I stays empty @RobertDresler

Comment: I get the data to the user but not the Table View so there is probably a problem with the table view @LohithKorupolu

Comment: Register the cells first in `viewDidLoad()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not set delegate and datasource for your `tableView` in your storyboard do it programmatically:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   //Add these 2 lines, might be missed.
    self.tableview.delegate = self
    self.tableview.dataSource = self

    retrieveUsers()
}
```

Comment: Thank, that's exactly what was missing, I had also missed : tableview.register(UINib(nibName: "UserCardTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "UserCell")

Answer (score 0):

CheckList:

1. Set tableView Delegate and Datasource

   self.tableview.delegate = self

   self.tableview.dataSource = self
2. Registered custom `tableViewCell`?

   let cellNIb = UINib.init(nibName:"Identifier_Name", bundle: nil)
   register(cellNIb, forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
3. check the return count of `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int` 
   ​

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that you forgot:

- Set `dataSource` of your table view as your controller. If you don't do it, your `tableView` won't want any data. So set it in controller's `viewDidLoad`

  ```
  tableview.dataSource = self
  ```
- If you created custom xib for your cell, don't forget to register your custom cell for table view (also you can do it in `viewDidLoad`)

  ```
  tableview.register(UINib(nibName: "UserCardTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "UserCell")
  ```

---

If you need `UITableViewDelegate` methods like `didSelectRowAt` too, don't forget to set `delegate` of your table view as your controller too

```
tableview.delegate = self
```